# Nested Mount Best Practice

Tags: mount, symlink, ln

I have two filesystems that need to be mounted on a RedHat system /apps and /apps/label. /apps will have several sub directorates and label will just have files FTP'd to it.

Would it be better to mount /apps/label over /apps or to create a new mount point /label and link it to /apps/label? What are the best practices?

/etc/fstab

```
/dev/mapper/appvg-apps          /apps                   ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/labelvg-label       /apps/label                  ext4    defaults        0 0
```

or

```
/dev/mapper/appvg-apps          /apps                   ext4    defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/labelvg-label       /label                  ext4    defaults        0 0  
# ln -sf /label /apps/label
```

Comment: huh, both fstab examples are the same ?

Comment: It sounds like you just want `/apps` and `/apps/label` mount points. Why do your symlink thing if you don't need it? It may not even work properly if the FTP server `chroot`s for example...

Comment: With nested mounts, there's always the (small) risk that you accidentally create files on the outer mount under the directory where the inner file system was supposed to be mounted, which then get shadowed by the inner mount, so I wouldn't nest them unless necessary, personally